# Is the Ontology of the Semantic Web dead?

Tags: ontology

Is the Ontology of the Semantic Web dead?

I am developing a work plan for my thesis about "a knowledge base through a set ontology for interest groups around wetlands." I have been researching and developing ontologies this but not sure many things, eg I have some doubts?

Which will be the modelling language for ontologies? Methodology for ontologies which is better, or otk methodology? Is there any program that does an analysis of the textual corpus and extraction of the specific terms of the domain of study as does Cratilo 2 (software developed by professors Jorge Antonio Mejia, Francisco Javier Alvarez and John Albeiro Sánchez, Institute of Philosophy the University of Antioquia. Cratilo enables lexical analysis of texts, identifying the words that appear,) its frequency and its location in the text. Through a process of recognition, Cratylus identifies all the words in the text and builds a database becomes the draft analysis of the work.

There is another program to fill or find terms like Cratylus? These relevant terms Catrilo finding can be used to fill a knowledge base? that there are alternatives open semantic framework and performs this framwork
what are the advantages of protecting, what alternatives are there? Automatically creates the RDF OWL and XML? how does it work Tails? JENA? SESAME?

Comment: Could you please provide links to the apps you mention? Cratylus, Catrilo, Cratilo, Cratilo 2. If it is all the same software and it is just typos, then please fix, thanks!

Comment: [Cross-post](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/283163/63183) of the question.

Comment: I count around 10 different questions here, although I don't understand all of them. What is your main question? Currently your post is much too broad to be reasonably answered. Please try to focus it, or split it up into different questions.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu - you have crossposted this to data science.

Comment: sorry I did not know that I could not place them in several places at once, anyway I did not know which was the best place for the question, sorry me for the problem, that would be great moderators placed a regulation that should and do not, like the redditiquete on reddit.

Tell me if I will  should delete it from here.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't say 'dead'.  There might be less dicussion of it, as people consider things to be stable enough that there are useful products that it's less hyped.

I'd personally advise against making a new ontology without first consulting the field to see if there's something that you can make use of -- unless you've already encoded/catloged all of our data, you're not going to want to go to the trouble of building crosswalks to the main ontologies in the field so that people can actually use your data.

As you mention wetlands, I'd suggest trying either the [American Geophysical Union's Earth & Space Science Informatics](http://essi.agu.org/) group, or the [Federation of Earth Science Information Partners' Semantic Web](http://wiki.esipfed.org/index.php/Semantic_Web) group. You might also check the [Marine Metadata Interoperability](https://marinemetadata.org/) project, as they host & link to a number of controlled vocabularies.  It's possible that the [EarthCube](http://earthcube.org/) or [GEONgrid](http://www.geongrid.org/) communities might have answers, too, but I'm not as familiar with their work to know for sure.

(disclaimer : I'm one of the mailing list maintainers for the AGU ESSI list.  Yes the website is out of date, but our webmaster changed jobs and I don't know what his status is).